# Any way to define WP_UPLOADS_URL (like WP_CONTENT_URL)?

Tags: uploads

Is there any way to define custom constants, i.e.
WP_UPLOADS_DIR
or
WP_UPLOADS_URL

like `WP_CONTENT_URL`??

`UPLOADS` constant changes both URL and DIR, but I want to set them separately.

Comment: Have you tried adding them to `wp-config`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since version 3.5 you can define constant 'UPLOADS' like:

```
define('UPLOADS','myfiles');
```

where 'myfiles' is a folder location relative to ABSPATH. If the folder does not exist, it will be automatically created.

**EDIT**: It will only work, if a new folder is located below website's Document Root folder ( ABSPATH ). To put it outside of ABSPATH tree, we cannot use 'define' method. Prior to version 3.5, two more options were available on 'Settings -> Media' screen: '*Store uploads in this folder*' and '*Full URL path to files*'. These are hidden now, when both options, 'upload_path' and 'upload_url_path' in wp_options table are blank ( default ). If you can use phpMyAdmin, set 'upload_path' to non-blank value. Any character will do. This will re-enable missing options of 'Settings -> Media' screen. If phpMyAdmin cannot be used, add the following code to the current theme's functions.php file:

```
/*  Re-enables 'upload_path' and 'upload_url_path'
    on 'Settings -> Media'
*/
function fpw_populate_upload_path() {
    if( is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
        if ( empty( get_option( 'upload_path' ) ) )
            update_option( 'upload_path', '/' );
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'fpw_populate_upload_path' );
```

Now, you can set the path and URL of the new uploads folder, using 'Settings -> Media' screen. Done.

Comment: I knew that, but it doesnt have variation of _DIR and _URL types, like `WP_CONTENT_DIR` and `WP_CONTENT_URL`...
that's why I was searching.. However , +1

Comment: Define 'UPLOADS' is quite limited. It does work when your new location is below the root of your website ( ex. public_html/myfiles ). In other cases it is better to use two options in 'wp_options' table: 'upload_path' and 'upload_url_path'. On fresh WordPress installation these two options are blank ( default ). In that case 'Settings -> Media' does not show two fields: 'Store uploads in this folder' and 'Full URL path to files'.  If you can use phpMyAdmin, edit 'upload_path' making its value non-blank. Save it. Go to 'Settings -> Media' and finish the job there.

Comment: `/wp-admin/options.php` gives access to `upload_path` and `upload_url_path`. Then there is the `upload_dir` filter available.

Comment: Yes, you are right.I tend to forget about options.php.

Comment: @FrankP.Walentynowicz, thanks I had spent 3 days trying to get my WP install to recognize the uploads directory was not in the root of the site.I didn't realize I was actually outside the root of the site until I read your post. Using the options in the wp_options table resolved things for me.